# List Index out of bounds / range

Tags: python, dataframe

I have to build a automated import for reports. These can vary between csv files and excel files. I got the part where the csv is read in and split (need to split and rearrange the date) working. My problem starts when I try to read a excel from pycharm. All of this works in jupyter notebook, but seems to run into an error in pycharms (I already kmow that I can't copy stuff from jn to pych. due to indents and stuff..)
This is my code and I would like to know where and why my index runs out of range. The date comes in as 'yyyy/mm/dd'

```
datum = []
try:
    if df.columns[0] == "Day":
        for line in df["Day"]:
            date_emer = line.split("/")
            date_new = [date_emer[2], date_emer[1], date_emer[0]]
            date_new_join = "".join(date_new)
            datum.append(int(date_new_join))
            date_correct = datetime(year=int(date_new_join[0:4]), day=int(date_new_join[4:6]), month=int(date_new_join[6:8]))
            df["Day"] = date_correct
            print(df)
    elif df.columns[0] == "day":
        for line in df["day"]:
            date_emer = line.split("/")
            date_new = [date_emer[0], date_emer[1], date_emer[2]]
            date_new_join = "".join(date_new)
            datum.append(int(date_new_join))
            date_correct = datetime(year=int(date_new_join[0:4]), month=int(date_new_join[4:6]), day=int(date_new_join[6:8]))
            df["day"] = date_correct
            print(df)
    else:
        print("Unknown Column! Error!")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error Message: " +str(e))
```

This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sales_import_outbrain.py", line 99, in <module>
    raise e
  File "sales_import_outbrain.py", line 89, in <module>
    date_new = [date_emer[0], date_emer[1], date_emer[2]]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
year,month,day = line.split("/")
date_correct = datetime(year=int(year), day=int(day), month=int(month))
```

I think you can directly use this

Comment: if i use this i get the error ```not enough values to unpack```

Comment: it mean all date's not following `'yyyy/mm/dd'` format

Comment: can you `print` the content of `line`

Comment: the content of line is the column name: 
```Content of line: day```

Comment: in `line` it should always only date `yyyy/mm/dd`

Comment: I see. So I'm basically calling indexes that aren't there, but why is it working in jupyter notebook? Because when I print out line there it ony shows the yyyy/mm/dd...